# How to increase number count and display on dynamically added div jquery?

Tags: jquery, increment

I have a link on top of static div which is already loading by default (Div number 1).

As the picture illustrates, whenever I am clicking on the hyperlink the div is added underneath every last div that I did very well.  What I want to do is, as you can see in the picture, I have to increase the count of div numbers like 2, 3, 4 along with text called 'Div number... ' on dynamically added divs.

[image]

How can I achieve this by using jQuery?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have written thus far to achieve what you have in the screenshot?

Comment: It's only a append to do. You didn't even tried, did you?

Comment: It's not the case of trying, you've given us very little to work with so expect the answers to be off a vague assumption.

Comment: Try my code . I am sure it will work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward. Just append the new divs.

```
(function(){
  var div = 0;
  $(".create").click(function(){
    div++;
    $(".block").append('<div class="new_div">Div number '+div+'</div>');
  });
})();
```

As a DEMO : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/cicagustiani/024tygew/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Try **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/e43sf6d3/4/)**

**HTML**

```
 <div>
     <a id="lnk" href="#">Link to add more divs</a>
 </div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
 var count = 1;
 $("#lnk").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().append('<div class="divStyle">Div number ' + count + ' </div>');
    count++;
 });
```

**CSS**

```
 .divStyle {
     background-color:gray;
     margin-bottom:2px;
  }
```

Comment: Pleasure @user3667940 :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe my pseudocode gives you an idea

```
$('#linktoadd').click(function(){
    $('#divholder').append('<div class="foo">Div Number'+($('#divholder div').length +1) +'</div>');
 }
```

Comment: its pseudocode, the OP did not give any code example so what

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are putting div in a container  id "container".

the code of adding incrementing div no is.

```
 var no = $('div','#contianer').length; // will give you total no of div in that container.
var incno = parseInt(no,10)+1;
```

Comment: Hi dude,  I tried your code, but i didn't get any proper result.  Maybe I missed out something... 
var noofDivs = $('.assignContName').length; 
                alert(noofDivs);
                var incno = parseInt(noofDivs, 10) + 1;

I am getting alert as expected as incremental order.  How can i insert the value within the specific div?  For your kind information I have span tag within '.assignContName' where I have insert the value.

Comment: I tried some other method based on your logic, working fine. But for the sake of simplicity, I followed another stuffs.  I will copy your code will use when I need.  Thanks for your solutions dude.